# Java runs really slow on CentOS minimal install, but fast on normal install

Tags: java, linux, centos, redhat, dacapo

Using CentOS 6.2, both of these installations are on the same server:

After doing a 'minimal' install Java programs run incredibly slow. 
After doing a 'software development workstation' install Java programs run at normal speed.

Some information gathered so far:

- Enabling services not present in the minimal install, e.g., `irqbalance`, `cpuspeed` has not helped
- Have done benchmarks using [Phoronix](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/) suite to test CPU/RAM/HD speed. These tests all run fine on both installs.
- Have done benchmarks using [DaCapo](http://dacapobench.org/) suite (which is in Java). These tests all run *terribly* (that is, 5-50 times slower) on the minimal install.
- Have tried multiple versions of JRE: OpenJDK 6, Sun Java 6, Sun Java 7
- Have updated to the latest packages with yum
- Have verified this slowdown multiple times on two different servers.
- Both servers use Xeon dual core processors, and have 16GB of RAM or more

Anyone have any idea what could cause this?

Comment: The minimal install is possibly missing the --server JVM. Try to load java with "java --server -version" and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your response!. It returns: 
java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.6) (rhel-1.43.1.10.6.el6_2-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

The benchmarks run slowly with the -server option as well

Comment: are you sure you tried with sun java 7? should be best option. Install again and do java -version.

Answer (score 1):

when you test the oracle jdk was it the bin file from the oracle site?

The package from oracle should perform exactly the same: please download these rpms (they will install on centos 6 just fine)

[java_rpm](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/833212/java-1.6.0-sun-devel-1.6.0.29-1jpp.1.el5.x86_64.rpm)
[java_devel](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/833212/java-1.6.0-sun-devel-1.6.0.29-1jpp.1.el5.i586.rpm)

These are official packages (you need to install both). You also then need to do:

(select which java you want to use)

```
alternatives --config java
```

(select which javac you want to use)

```
alternative -- config javac
```